# Como bloquear caracteres NumberBox ou TextBox

Tags: javascript, c#

Tenho um formulário do `DevExtreme` e nesse formulário possuo um `NumberBox` que é de um campo telefone, mas esse campo aceita apenas `números` (óbvio), `.` e `,`, mas o telefone, pode ser do tipo `(xxx)xxxxx-xxxx` aceitando apenas hífen, parênteses e número, porém o meu campo não me permite fazer isso, o meu campo telefone é do tipo `string` então eu posso alterar de `NumberBox` para `TextBox`, porém com `TextBox` eu preciso limitar para aceitar apenas `números, hífens e parênteses`, sei que posso utilizar o `onkeypress` que chama uma função em JavaScript, mas não sei criar essa função, como posso fazer isso?

Não irei postar o código todo, pois é bem grande .

```
groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Bcx_telefone).CssClass("agTel")
.Editor(e => e.NumberBox().Width("100px").Max(9999999999).ID("agTelId"));
```

Por enquanto está como mostra acima, mas com `TextBox`, fica assim:

```
groupItems.AddSimpleFor(m => m.Bcx_telefone).CssClass("agTel")
.Editor(e => e.TextBox().Width("100px").MaxLength(15).OnKeyPress("key_press").ID("agTelId"));
```

JavaScript:

```
function key_press(e) {
    //Não sei como continuar e bloquear os caracteres 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em vez de usar o atributo `OnKeyPress`, use um *event handler*. Assim, com a função `.test()` você consegue cancelar o evento restringindo os caracteres permitidos com uma simples expressão regular (RegEx).

Retire do código a parte `.OnKeyPress("key_press")`. Você irá puxar o textbox pelo `id`, ficando desta forma:

```
document.getElementById("agTelId").onkeypress = function(e){
   if(!/[()-\d]/.test(e.key)) e.preventDefault();
}
```

**A Regex:** `[()-\d]`

Os caracteres dentro dos colchetes `[]` indicam quais os caracteres são permitidos, no caso os parênteses `()`, o hífen `-` e qualquer número de 0 a 9, representado pela expressão `\d`.

Exemplo para teste:

```js
document.getElementById("agTelId").onkeypress = function(e){
   if(!/[()-\d]/.test(e.key)) e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="agTelId">
```

Comment: Eu vejo que seu código funciona executando aqui, mas no meu não funciona, talvez eu esteja fazendo algo errado, mas eu removi o OnKeyPress e adicionei o document.get.... dentro do <script></script>, estou certo ou deve ser declarado fora?

Comment: Veja se mostra erro no console?

Comment: Teria como inciar um chat para eu te mostrar o print?

Answer (score 1):

Por existirem diferentes tipos de teclado, e essa validação estar no client-side, não é possível cobrir 100% dos casos. Por isso, mantenha sempre as suas validações primeiramente no server-side, e replique-as no client-side.

Para conseguir isso com o evento KeyPress, controle com uma expressão regular:

```
function validate(e) {
  var _event = e || window.event;

  if (_event.type === 'paste') {
      key = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  } else {
      var key = _event.keyCode || _event.which;
      key = String.fromCharCode(key);
  }
  var regex = /[0-9]|\(|\)|\-/;
  if(!regex.test(key)) {
    _event.returnValue = false;
    if (_event.preventDefault) _event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

A expressão regular que eu fiz foi `/[0-9]|\(|\)|\-/`. Ela considera números de 0 a 9, parênteses e hifens.

Preste atenção no [`Event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), pois é ele que cancela o evento do KeyPress, quando alguma tecla foi rejeitada pela expressão regular.

Comment: Me parece bom, porém por algum motivo que não sei explicar isso não funciona no meu, vou debuggar para ver se consigo encontrar o motivo

Comment: Eu agradeço a sua resposta, vou aceitar a resposta do sam, pois ele me ajudou bastante aqui no chat, depois analisarei para ver o porque não consegui dessa maneira